# Form is Submitting Although Error Handled on Blank Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, error-handling

I am trying to submit a form with a little error handling. when the fields are empty there will be a warning and it shouldn't be saved on DB. if the fields are filled there should be a success alert. My case is still the empty value is being saved.

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="add" onclick="emptyHandling();" name="_add" class="btn btn-primary btn-size" value="Add"/>
```

//FORM SUBMIT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            async: false,
            autoUpload: false,
            success: function(response){
                $('.statusMsg').html('');
                if(response.status == 1){
                    $('#form')[0].reset(); //FORM TO RESET AFTER SUBMISSION
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<p class="alert alert-success">'+response.message+'</p>'); // REPONSE MESSAGE                    
                }else{
                    $('.statusMsg').html(alert(response.message));
                }
                $('#form').css("opacity","");
                $(".submit").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });
});

//ERROR HANDLING - TRIGGERED ON CLICK
function emptyHandling(){
    var inv = $("#inv").val();
    if(inv == ''){
        var message = "Field Left Empty";
        alertMessage(message);
    }else{
        successMessage();
    }
    return false; // THIS IS BEING RETURNED FALSE
}

//WARNING ALERT
function alertMessage(titleMessage){
    swal({
        title: titleMessage,
        text: "Mandatory Fields are Required to be Filled",
        type: "warning",
        confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-danger"
    });
}
```

The return is made false on error handling which should stop the next processes. I am not really sure of where the mistake is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove onclick from your `submit` button and move that function call inside your `form` submit handler . Then , inside this check if the validation function return true/false depending on this execute your ajax call.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //call function..
    if (emptyHandling()) {
      //your ajax...
      console.log("inside ajax....")
    }
  });
});

//ERROR HANDLING - TRIGGERED ON CLICK
function emptyHandling() {
  var flag = true
  var inv = $("#inv").val();
  if (inv == '') {
    var message = "Field Left Empty";
    alertMessage(message);
    flag = false
  } else {
    successMessage();
  }
  return flag; // return flag//
}

//WARNING ALERT
function alertMessage(titleMessage) {
  //swal...
  console.log(titleMessage)
}

function successMessage() {
  console.log("All good...")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="inv">
  <input type="submit" id="add" name="_add" class="btn btn-primary btn-size" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Swati, I don't think this way is efficient. as per this case, I am missing my success alert.

Comment: See updated answer its working fine . What doesn't work or am i missing something here ?

Comment: Thanks Swati. You got it right. Can you please explain why it didn't work when I make the method false without initiating.

Comment: Because you have not connected both function and event handler together  . Your fn must be returning false but , you have another event handler for form submit ..where that function has no effect so to avoid this you can call your function inside your event handler and depending on validation result you can execute your ajax.